# Inherit width from indirect ancestor

Tags: css

I have the following HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
    <ul class="sub_menu">
      <!-- full of <li> sub menu items -->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
    <ul class="sub_menu">
      <!-- full of <li> sub menu items -->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The `#nav` is 100% the width of the browser window.

Using only CSS I want to float the `Menu Item`s side by side inside a container that has similar CSS:

```
{ width: 1000px;  margin: 0 auto; }
```

But I want the `.sub_menu`s to be the same width as `#nav`.

How can this be done without changing the HTML?

Comment: width and margin aren't inherited, so it's not clear what sort of inheritance you're trying to break here.

Comment: @BoltClock yeah, I wasnt sure about the title, it could probably do with renaming to something more appropriate, but at the time of writing this I just couldnt come up with a succinct title for this question - if you have a suggestion please let me know and I will re-title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `position: relative` the `#nav`, do your thing with the `li` and then `position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0` the `.sub_menu`.

This way `.sub_menu` is the same width as `#nav` regardless of the width of `li`. You'll have to add and adjust some more styles to make it look pretty and in position but I'll leave that to you.

An additional requirement is that `li` will stay `position: static` as the position of `.sub_menu` must be relative to `#nav`.

EDIT: @simon's answer is pretty much an implementation of mine, but OP has left a comment there indicating that it isn't adequate. We're still unsure of what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

here you go:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXZQMo

The Subnav UL has now the same width as the parent li

```
#nav { width: 1000px;  margin: 0 auto; }
ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}
ul li{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width:auto;
}
ul li:hover ul{
  display:block;
}
ul li ul{
  display:none;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  min-height:20px;
  transition:all 0.3s;
}
ul li ul li{
  display:block;
  float:none;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. however your CSS doesnt include the container that the Menu Items should float in - this container should have CSS like this: `{ width: 1000px;  margin: 0 auto; }`

Comment: i ve added the over effect and 2 example submenu items
Please specify your request - i dont understand what u need

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wibeqitawe/1/edit?html,css,output)):

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }

#nav, .sub_menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}

#nav > li > a {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

#nav > li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sub_menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  top: 30px
}
```

This puts all the buttons one after another and keeps the submenu 100% width

Comment: thanks for this. however your CSS doesnt include the container that the Menu Items should float in - this container should have CSS like this: `{ width: 1000px;  margin: 0 auto; }`

Comment: @Jimmery, CSS cannot be used to create HTML elements. As such, if the "container" you speak of isn't `#nav` as we seem to think it is, you'll probably have to change your HTML structure.

Comment: @simon the code in the comment i just made was copy and pasted from my question. if you cant see that code in my question (hint: its the second block of code) then i cant help you

Comment: @Jimmery why so rude? There is **no block** in your code. If you think your `CSS` code is a block then I cannot help you as well...

Comment: @simon do a search for `{ width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; }` - then you'll find that this is in my original question